# Return value from array if URLs match in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have the following array `$myarr` and the $url value as such :

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/jane-doe/testingideas.html";


stdClass Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [updated] => 2015-01-08 17:22:23.279210
                    [url] => http://www.example.com/jane-doe/testingideas.html
                    [score] => 21.053322

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [updated] => 2015-01-08 17:22:23.279226
                    [url] => http://www.example.com/john-doe/ideas.html
                    [score] => 18.889984
                )
 )

)
```

The array has over 2000 values. I copied 2 to simplify things. I need to retrieve the score based on the URL. This is the code I wrote:

```
  $myarr = $output->items;
    foreach ($myarr as $val){
       if ($val->url == $url ) {
       $score = round($val->score); 
    } else $score = 'N/A';
    }
```

This does not work because it doesn't find any scores, even when the URLs are matching.

I also trimmed both URLs to remove any whitespaces but I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are unsetting `$score` in each loop, you'd better do:

```
$myarr = $output->items;
$score = 'N/A';
foreach ($myarr as $val){
    if ($val->url == $url ) {
       $score = round($val->score); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
foreach ($myarr as $items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {

        if ($item->url == $url ) {
            $score = round($val->score); 
        } else {
            $score = 'N/A';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your answer doesn't work its the same thing I did. it doesn't match the urls. sorry I forgot to add a line of code sorry. But that wasn't wrong. the actual urls are both outputted and they are matching to the eye. but the code doesn't resolve the score in those cases.

Comment: @stacknoob If you have a array that contains this(What you have shown in the question), but you assign it like this: `$myarr = $output->items;` what's then the output of `print_r($myarr);` ?! (Also try `trim()` with both values so there are no hidden whitespaces)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/jane-doe/testingideas.html";
$myarr = $output->items;
foreach ($myarr as $val){
   if (strcmp($val->url,$url) == 0) {
        $score = round($val->score); 
   } else {
        $score = 'N/A';
   }
}
```

Comment: I used this then added after N/A case echo strcmp($val->url,$thisurl); and it returns numbers from -512 to 1280

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trim()` to make sure there is no excesive whitespace:

```
if (trim($item->url) == trim($url))
```